# a line perpendicular to a given line

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, computational-geometry, mathematical-modeling

I am confused now,

> I have a 2D line. If its equation is $r = x\cos(\theta) + y\sin(\theta)$,
>   then what will be the line which is perpendicular to that line?

Where $r, \theta$ is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

I know this is very simple, any suggestions please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line perpendicular to your line is

$$-x \sin{\theta} + y \cos{\theta} = C$$

That said, looking at your reference, that equation is the equation of a line perpendicular to a radius vector from the origin at angle $\theta$ with respect to the positive $x$ axis, at a distance $r$ from the origin.

Comment: thank you very much. what is the general rule to get it, please. wish to learn

Comment: Then general rule is a line perpendicular to $a x + b y = c_1$ is $-b x + a y = c_2$.

Comment: sorry for making confuse. i would like to know how it decide.. does make a vector? if so it wil be rotated vector, then how it would be...